# Webkit Performance Rendering 5-ish images

Tags: html, performance, webview, wkwebview

This relates to a webview in an app (iPad 2, so using WebKit).

It seems the layout is happening immediately, but it is not drawing to the screen immediately.

My HTML output looks somewhat similar to this example,

```
<div style="position:relative;width:1024px;height:768px;" data-reactid=".0.1.0">
    <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/d4e138d6-aa6b-41a6-878b-8ee26ba450a3" style="position:absolute;left:51.055712117927555px;top:93.9596791675699px;width:972.9442878820724px;height:157.16280078040322px;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWP4////fwAJ+wP9CNHoHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$notation-1728">
    <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/b860fbef-8b40-4a09-9d00-2575fac9bb8c" style="position:absolute;left:4.661608497723819px;top:271.12247994797315px;width:1019.3383915022762px;height:191.79189247778018px;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWP4////fwAJ+wP9CNHoHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$notation-1729">
    <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/2b655007-792a-4ad7-8fcd-42b9ece6ec2f" style="position:absolute;left:4.661608497723819px;top:482.9143724257533px;width:1019.3383915022762px;height:188.46217212226315px;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQImWP4////fwAJ+wP9CNHoHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);" data-reactid=".0.1.0.$notation-1730">
</div>
```

- The images are being placed on the page via React
- There are three images using blob urls
- All blobs are generated from base64 strings at start up, and this is not recalculated (confirmed this is the case)
- There is a small amount of CSS positioning and other styles
- The base64 strings are no larger than 60kb, so the images are no larger than 40kb
- The images are scaled down

You are able to navigate to different sections, which will replace the images with a similar amount of images at slightly different positions (done via React).

However, changing the section is slow. It feels like 400-600ms to see the new section.

I had an implementation that wasn't using react: each section would be placed on a div and all but the current section would positioned off screen. When you change section, I would just move the divs. This process was in the milliseconds, but it still took the same 400-600ms to see the changes on the screen. This lead me to conclude the second sentence: that the layout is happening immediately, but it is not drawing to the screen at the same time.

Am I correct in thinking that the layout and drawing happen at different times? And are there any optimisations I could be using?